# AngularJS: select option

Tags: angularjs

Here are my objects within array:

```
[
    {"name":"someName1","label":"someLabel1"},
    {"name":"someName2","label":"someLabel2"},
    {"name":"someName3":"label":"someLabel3"}
]
```

How could I form select option with ng-options?

This [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) unfortunately doesn't pop the solution in my head or I am blinded by the complexity of my code, since this select field should be inside ng-repeat.

Imagine, all in ng-repeat:

someInput,
someInput,
select option (above case),
somethingMore

I have no idea how to proper code and connect models in this situation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just do:

```
<select ng-options="item.name as item.label for item in myArray">
```

item.name is the value that will be matched/stored in the provided ng-model and item.label is the text that will be displayed to the user.

Here is [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GTk0bjRFOwerzbCR2U7z?p=preview) along with an ng-repeat usage example.